How to create dashboard to view the TEST EXECUTION progress of each tester in KIWI
As a manager I want to know what the work-load/performance of individual teams and engineers is. I can use this information either for performance review or for capacity planning of future work.
As per the document mentioned here https://kiwitcms.org/blog/kiwi-tcms-team/2019/03/03/legacy-reports-become-telemetry/ we can create the Performance telemetry but I could not find that option in my Kiwi login. Can you please help me on how to add performance telemetry in my Kiwi login

